# Reading a Maths equation

Tags: number-theory

Hello I have encountered an equation from number theory that I don't quite understand. I am working on my own, so it is difficult to know what I am looking at or decide what to search for on Google to gain understanding. I understand the symbol for integer.

Can someone please explain this equation to me in detail as well as refer websites to me that may provide some useful notes:

$Z[\sqrt{−5}] = \{a + b \sqrt{−5} : a, b ∈ Z\} ⊂ C$,

Thank you.

Comment: The tick in the equation is a square root sign.

Comment: I do not believe $a,b\in \mathbb Z$ means what you say.  I believe it simply means that $a$ and $b$ are integers. the entire expression simply identifies a specific subset of the complex numbers.

Comment: Could you explain the meaning of the symbols as well as the notation.

Comment: The symbols mean:  $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is defined to be the set of all combinations of the form $a+b\sqrt{-5}$.  For example, all integers are in this set (just take $b=0$.  Similarly, $\sqrt{-5}$ is in this set (take $\{a,b\}=\{0,1\}$.  If, say, we identify $\sqrt{-5}$ with $\sqrt{5}i$ then we can think of this set as a subset of the complex numbers.

Comment: What does the curve with c mean?

Comment: This equation simply describes a ring of [quadratic integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_integer). Here $\Bbb{Z}$ denotes the set of integers — the numbers $0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,\dotsc$, to keep it simple — and $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ simply denotes the set of numbers of the form $a + \sqrt{-5} b$ with $a,b \in \Bbb{Z}$, which is a subset of the set of complex numbers $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: In general, to say That $A\subset B$ means "$A$ is a subset of $B$".  In this case, "$C$" is, presumably, meant to be $\mathbb C$, the complex numbers.  To be precise, the defined set is not a subset of the complex numbers until you identify $\sqrt{-5}$ with either $\sqrt{5}i$ or $-\sqrt{5}i$.

Comment: The $\subset$ symbol means "is a subset of".  In this case, it means that the set of numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt{-5}$ is a subset of the complex numbers (usually denoted $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbf{C}$ or something like that).

Comment: I think it is a little bit advanced for the OP as he/she mentions on his/her profile that he/she is in High school. However: as lulu points it out, $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ is a notation to mean $a$ is an integer and $b$ is an integer. The square root of a negative number is a so-called complex number. If you don't know what it is, I recommend you the Wikipedia page about "Complex number" before you try to understand the notation in your question.

Comment: Thank you to all commenters and anwerers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is says is that the set of numbers in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt {-5}]$ is all numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt{-5}$ where $a,b$ are integers and it forms a subset of $\Bbb C$, the complex numbers.  Some examples are $2+3\sqrt{-5}, -4-999\sqrt{-5}, 15$ (because $b$ may be zero), and $8 \sqrt {-5}$ (because $a$ may be zero).  This is a definition of the set, so in a sense no explanation is needed.  It will turn out that this is a ring, which they will probably go on to prove.  That means you can add, subtract, and multiply these numbers and that multiplication distributes over addition like you are used to in the integers.  Any such set $Z[\sqrt{k}]$ is a ring.

Answer (score 2):

This is a definition of the set Z[-sqrt(5)]

The set $Z[\sqrt{-5}] $

$=$   is

$\{ a+b \sqrt{-5} $    numbers of this form

$ : a, b$   the numbers

$ ∈\mathbb{ Z} $  are members of the set Z

$ \} ⊂ C $   ia a subset of the complex numbers.